# Cannot take input with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I just can't read with scanner. I read a lot of other posts but i just cannot understand what in the world is wrong with this. I have tried with Buffer read but it gives error as well.
I just can't figure it out. What should i do?

```
This is the error:

    Start : 1
Exit : 2
=> 1
Enter your name
=> 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at pcGame/pkg.GameLogic.characterCreation(GameLogic.java:28)
    at pcGame/pkg.GameLogic.main(GameLogic.java:41)
```

This is the code:

```
        package pkg;

import java.util.Scanner;

public final class GameLogic {
    
    public void gameMenu() {
        System.out.print("Start : 1\nExit : 2\n=> ");
        int opt = 1;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        opt = input.nextInt();
        
        switch(opt) {
        case 1:
            input.close();
            return;
            
        case 2:
            System.exit(0);
        }
        input.close();
    }
    
    public void characterCreation() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter your name\n=> ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter your \n=> ");
        String story = input.nextLine();
        
        //Player.initialize("name", "story"); //Initializes Player
        
        input.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameLogic game = new GameLogic();
        game.gameMenu();
        game.characterCreation();
        
        
        
        while(true) {
            //Game Happens
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that you have too many Scanners handling System.in and you are closing them (which also closes `System.in` and prevents you from using it later). Create one Scanner and pass it to methods which need it.

Comment: And do not close it until the program ends. Closing a scanner also closes the underlying stream. And once you've closed System.in, it's almost impossible to reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to remove `input.close();` statements